# Samba 3.5.9 - join domain specific OU - net join ads

Tags: samba, active-directory

Our Unix team often uses Samba to join machines to the domain. The command they have traditionally used is:

```
net join ADS -w [domain name] -U [username]
```

I am one of our AD admins and I am trying to find out how to get them to be able to join to a specific OU so we can have all of the Samba machines organized in AD. From all of my research, it seems that this should work:

```
net join ads "Servers/Samba" -w [domain] -U [username]
```

This still allows the machine to join to the domain without issue but it keeps ending up in the 'computers' container and we receive no errors.

I have made sure on the AD side that the user they are using have join domain rights and create/delete computer objects on both the "servers" OU tree and the "computers" container.

What am I missing? I can't find much documentation on the Samba net commands without having access to a unix box with it. Also, I noticed in most examples people always had 'net ads join...' rather than 'net join ads...' - our Unix admin got errors when trying to use net ads join. I do not know why our syntax seems different then most examples I found but I wanted to point it out.

Here are some sites that support my research:
https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/domain-member.html
http://www.members.optushome.com.au/~wskwok/poptop_ads_howto_6a.htm

Answer (score 1):

After going back and forth with our Unix guy I decided to set Samba up on a test box I had and eventually got it to work with the following command:

> Net ads join -w [DOMAIN] -U [username] createcomputer="servers/samba"

I had to also configure some sections of /etc/samba/smb.conf - I am not sure which of them are required but they were:

Workgroup = CONTOSO

security = ads

realm = contoso.com

Password server = DC.contoso.com

Sever role = member server

*hint if it doesn't exist, create it under the global section of the file

*EDIT*

The Unix guy tried my command and got "ADS support not compiled in". This is most likely because I am using Samba 4.1.6 and he is using 3.6 or 7 something.

At this point we either need to upgrade Samba or figure out how to compile Samba so that it supports ADS.

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue with Latest version of Centos (7) and Active Directory 2012.  When using 'net rpc join' the system always goes into the Domain Computers OU.  samba-winbind is 4.1.1.  didn't have samba installed bc shouldn't need it.  didn't make a difference after installing it.

Got it to work by changing from **net rpc join** to **net ads join**
  `net ads join -U <user> --server=<server> createcomputer=Servers`

I get DNS errors but I'll work on those separately.